# HTML form action using a php file outside of root directory?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, include

I am wondering, there are a few files I have kept outside of the root directory in a different directory and I am trying to use a HTML form to post info to a php file that sits OUTSIDE the root directory

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a proxy script... something which *is* inside the web directory, but all it does is include the appropriate "protected" file:

DOCROOT/form_handler.php

```
<?php
include "../secret/form_handler.php";
```

DOCROOT/form.html

```
...
<form action="form_handler.php">
...
```

This is, in fact, how many sites are setup (in essence at least). It is typical to place most of your scripts outside the DOCROOT like this for in the rare case where Apache or similar does not parse your PHP (i.e. if it is misconfigured), it doesn't inadvertently send your source code.

Comment: How would I use HTML form to post to that though?

Comment: @Kalcoder: You'd need to make a file that is visible from the `public_html` directory, and make your form post to that. The only way you're going to get a file outside of the webroot to execute, is by including it from a file that is inside the webroot. - Or maybe with some fancy webserver configuration.

Comment: Good point @Leigh, this *is* possible with mod_rewrite (substitutions can be filesystem paths). If you are interested, you should submit that as an answer :-)

Comment: I need to be able to pass the info from a HTML form post to a php file that is in a folder on the same level as public_html, so in essence, posting not to a php file within public_html, is that possible?

Comment: then mod_rewrite is probably the only solution, map the notphp file from the form action on the php file in your php folder, as suggested above

Answer (score 3):

On my website, every form I start with this code:

```
<form action="action" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="i-action" value="do-whatever" />
```

This avoids the need for multiple proxy scripts because `action.php` will use the value of the hidden field to determine which php file should be called. Don't call the hidden field `action` if you post the form using Ajax because it can cause a conflict. Also, I have set the `.htaccess` file to remove the php extension, so you may need to add `.php` to `action` in your HTML code.

Here is `action.php`:

```
if (!empty($_POST['i-action']))
{
    $action = str_replace('.', '', $_POST['i-action']);
    $action = str_replace('/', '', $action);
    if (file_exists("../secret/directory/structure/$action".'.php'))
        require_once("../secret/directory/structure/$action".'.php');
}
```

I used `str_replace` to ensure hackers can't traverse to a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is posible. That directory should be hosted as separate site and then you can give absolute URL of the file as form action

Comment: that's not what he's asking for. Also "yes it's possible" is the worst kind of answer.

Comment: Not when the question includes a "Is that possible?"

Answer (score 0):

The file must be accesible from the web.
If "outside of Root" directory means outside of DocumentRoot, this wont be possible.

You could have a basic Controller in DocumentRoot which includes or dispatchs the action.

Comment: What if it was within the document root but just not in public_html ?

Comment: the file must be called from the web, so if you can call it, like f.e. /onedirunderdocumentroot/form.php you can use it. usually public_html is document_root, so everything below it can be accessed.