# Path to parent ignored in HTML form action string

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to link an action within a form to a php script:

```
<form action='../includes/RC_APP/process_login.php' method="post" name="login_form">
```

However it comes back with the error:
The requested URL /includes/RC_APP/process_login.php was not found on this server.

The PHP includes work fine:

```
<?php
include_once '../includes/RC_APP/db_connect.php';
include_once '../includes/RC_APP/functions.php';
```

My only thoughts are that the HTML will not process access above the web server document root directory while the PHP will; but this contradicts the security advice on keeping PHP include files outside of the web server's document root.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use base path and then your directory and file name.

Comment: Thanks, I thought basepath as a PHP function rather than an HTML one; will look it up and try to clarify.

Comment: Why are you posting directly to a file within an includes directory? seems a bit odd..

Comment: I am setting up a login process for the first time and following on from quite a lot of different advice, mainly utilising the approach put forward on http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL.

Comment: @AwladLiton have been looking through the uses of base path and I am not following your suggestion; would you be able to elaborate on how you are suggesting the use of base path in the form action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to my question, in that a form action cannot access anything above the document root directory:

[HTML form action using a php file outside of root directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390420/html-form-action-using-a-php-file-outside-of-root-directory)

Comment: By including a local PHP file that included a link to the actual script, as suggested by the linked Stack Overflow topic, the page is now working.  Thanks to everyone for their help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set base path in the head section.

like this:

```
<head>
<base href="your_site/sub_directory/">
</head>
```

The base tag makes everything link differently, including same-page anchor links to the base tag's url instead, e.g:

```
<a href='?update=1'>A link to this page</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href='your_site/sub_directory/?update=1' title='Some title'>A link to the base tag's page instead</a>
```

if you need to go another folder in same directory in base path e.g a folder includes in the basepath directory link that in this way :

```
 <a href='includes/'>A link to this page</a>
```

if you need to go another parent folder of base path e.g a folder includes  :

```
 <a href='..includes/'>A link to this page</a>
```

see more details: [Is it recommended to use the <base> html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I am not sure how this would alleviate the issue as it is not a sub-directory of the document root that is the issue but a directory above the document root.
Even with the Base tag in the Head of the HTML, the error is the same; it seems to be dropping the ../ parent specifier.

Comment: I think I have found the answer to my question, in that a form action cannot access anything above the document root directory:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390420/html-form-action-using-a-php-file-outside-of-root-directory